# PHP variable undefined in included file

Tags: php, ssi

I need to be able to include a PHP file using the Apache SSI, not the PHP include directive.

In page.php I have:

```
<body>
<?php
$text = "This is text";
?>
<!--#include virtual="file.php" -->
</body>
```

In file.php I have:

```
<p>This is a test</p>
<?php
echo "<p>".$text."</p>";
?>
```

The first line of text is displayed but then I get a error "Undefined variable in file.php line 3."

I thought that the SSI was an inline substitution so there should be no scoping issues? What fine print did I miss?
John

Comment: You nearly got it right, BUT: "inline" of what? The apache mechanisms certainly cannot work inside the php engine, those are different levels. The inclusion happens inside the processing of the request in apache, not side php. So the first scripts execution produces the markup text holding the SSI inclusion, then and only then that inclusion can be processed by apache. But that means: the first interpretation step has been left, so all variables in there are lost.

Comment: The documentation  (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/ssi.html)  states that the `virtual` directive takes the evaluated output of your included `file.php` file. So your `file.php` php file is being evaluated first and the result included. The documentation also warns that this is more or less to include static content. Why can you not just use the php-includes?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Knew there was fine print somewhere. I am looking for a hack that allows me to include the file from either a PHP file or an HTML. The real code checks to see if the variable exists before trying to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When `page.php` is executed by the php processor, it knows nothing about the apache include - that just looks like an HTML comment to it. So it just executes the php code that it sees, and then writes out the rest as html, producing something like this:

```
<body>
<!--#include virtual="file.php" -->
</body>
```

In the next step apache, will see the `#include` and try to execute `file.php`. But at that stage the `$text` variable has long since gone. Since `file.php` is executed as a standalone file, it's obviously going to generate an error when you try to access the `$text` variable.